# Auto generated makefile command

Tags: makefile

I have 3 files: node.h, node.c and main.c
If the Makefile is

```
CFLAGS += -std=c99 -g -Wall
run: node
    ./node

node: node.o main.o
```

Then, when I run `make`, these commands are run

```
cc -std=c99 -g -Wall   -c -o node.o node.c
cc -std=c99 -g -Wall   -c -o main.o main.c
cc   node.o main.o   -o node
./node
```

I guess the first two lines are generated because

- First, `make`try to run `node` but it cannot find `node`.
- Thus, `make` holds `run` and goes to the next target, which is `node` at line 4.
- Then, `make` sees the dependencies `node.o` and `main.o`. At this time, it knows that it must create object files `node.o` and `main.o`

However, I cannot understand why the third command is generated

```
cc   node.o main.o   -o node
```

In an attempt to explore this mystery, I observe that if `node` at line 2 is changed to `node1`, an error will occur

```
CFLAGS += -std=c99 -g -Wall
run: node1
    ./node1

node1: node.o main.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules:

> **Linking a single object file**
>
> n is made automatically from n.o by running the linker (usually called ld) via the C compiler. The precise recipe used is ‘$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES)  $(LDLIBS)’.
>
> This rule does the right thing for a simple program with only one source file. It will also do the right thing if there are multiple object files (presumably coming from various other source files), one of which has a name matching that of the executable file.

When you changed from node to `node1`, there is no longer a `node1.c` (therefore no implicit `node1.o`, and therefore the implicit rule does not apply).

Comment: Nice. My gut tells me there must be some implicit rules, but I cannot find the documents. Thank you.